# Scheduling posts on wordpress adds wrong seconds as post_date

Tags: wp-cron, cron

When scheduling a post in wordpress, e.g. 15:50, I always see that as time there are always seconds added at the end, e.g. 15:50:48, which ruins my cronjobs and makes them run 1 minutes later (if I run wp cron every minute), because if a post is scheduled for 15:50:48, it will not be posted on the cron for 15:50:00-01, instead it will wait a minute later. My question is why is wordpress adding random seconds when scheduling (like 48 seconds or 58 seconds?) which I haven't defined at all.

Edit: Easily this can be reproduced when you schedule any post at any time (e.g. 17:50) and look up in the database. You would see something like 17:50:48 for the post_date.
[image: Example]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry

Comment: Note that `15:50:48` is still `15:50`, but not `15:50:00` it's an important distinction. We know what you mean as would any other human being with a common understanding, but computers aren't sentient. Perhaps when you set the time it was 48 seconds into whichever minute you were in?

Comment: Yep, but I am scheduling. In the schedule i set 17 o'clock with 0 minutes. Seconds I have not defined, so they should may be 00 as well

Comment: tbh this sounds like something WP Core itself should address, a Trac bug ticket might be more appropriate than a Stack Exchange question

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44597 <- Created it